# React animation for moving an element from one parent to another

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I am trying to create an animation for moving a child element from one parent element to another using React.

A user should be able to click on an element and see it move into another div.

I made a simple demo component (without the animation) to show what I mean. When an element is clicked, the state updates and the elements are re-rendered in the correct place.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    list: ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Emily', 'Frank'],
    top: [0, 1, 2],
    bottom: [3, 4, 5]
  }

  moveDown = (item) => {
    let { top, bottom } = this.state
    this.setState({
      top: top.filter(x => x !== item),
      bottom: [...bottom, item]
    })
  }

  moveUp = (item) => {
    let { top, bottom } = this.state
    this.setState({
      top: [...top, item],
      bottom: bottom.filter(x => x !== item)
    })
  }

  render() {
    let { top, bottom, list } = this.state
    return (
      <div style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          alignItems: 'center',
          height: '90vh',
          width: '100%'
        }}>
        <div>
          {top.map((item) =>
            <div
              onClick={() => this.moveDown(item)}
              style={{color:'red'}}>{list[item]}</div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          {bottom.map((item) =>
            <div
              onClick={() => this.moveUp(item)}
              style={{color:'green'}}>{list[item]}</div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Codepen demo: https://codepen.io/ee92/pen/LqrBjL?editors=0010

Big appreciation to and thanks in advance for any help or advice on how to achieve this div-to-div animation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No it's not possible**

It's not possible to animate in that way because the DOM thinks you're removing a `div` and then adding a new `div`. Even though it's the same `div` to you, the DOM doesn't have that context. Animations are controlled by changes to CSS, not HTML.

**...but here's how to do it**

If you actually need both lists to stay in different `div`s the best you can do is either:

1. Animate the `old item` to the `new item` position, then delete the `old item` and show the `new item`.
2. Remove the `old item` and create a `new item` where the `old item` was and move it to the `new item` position.

Same concept, two ways of doing it.

I modified your existing sample to show a *simplified* version of option 2. Note that there are a number of animation decisions to make like what happens when the list gets smaller, how should the items change from red to green, etc., and I didn't try and objectively solve them. Also, this would be much easier if you could have all the `item`s for both lists in one `div`, and control their positions `absolute`ly. But if they need to end up in separate `div`s...

https://codepen.io/sallf/pen/VgBwQr?editors=0010

**What's going on**

1. Adding a `transition` to `.item` we can make the animation happen when we make adjustments to the `transform` property.
2. On item click we update our lists in state and add...
3. `transition.item` to know which item is animating...
4. `transition.startTop` to know the offset `y` position the item should start at relative to the bottom of the list it's moving to, and...
5. `transition.startAnim` as a flag to control the animation.
6. Since `transition`s need something to change before they'll animate, we use `setTimeout` to delay the change of `transition.startAnim` which basically causes the animation from the computed position, back to `0`.