# Picture animation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react, and i have written the card game. Now i want to work on its animation. I wanted to have an animation coming from up to down. I found [React animation for moving an element from one parent to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54660220/react-animation-for-moving-an-element-from-one-parent-to-another/54663061) question and made some changes there.

```
moveDown = (item) => {
        console.log("ANIMATION1 STARTED")
        const listBottom = this.bottomList.offsetTop + this.bottomList.clientHeight;
        const itemTop =    - listBottom + this.topList.offsetTop;
        const { top, bottom, rear, bottom2, bottom3, transition } = this.state;
        transition.item = item;
        transition.startTop = itemTop / 5;
        transition.startAnim = false;
        this.setState({
            top: top.filter(x => x !== item),
            rear: [...rear, item],
            transition
        })
        setTimeout(() => this.resetState(), 0.1);
        console.log("ANIMATION1 ENDED")
    }

    resetState = () => {
        const { transition } = this.state;
        transition.startAnim = true;


        this.setState({ transition }, () => {
          console.log('setState finished')
        })

    }
```

and i call it with

```
this.moveDown(this.state.top[0])
```

The problem is that, sometimes it show the animation, sometimes it just goes to the final place without animation. Why could it happen?

Comment: could you provide a demo, sharing a codepen or codesandbox link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see with the code that you are directly mutating the state. You should never mutate state and props directly. Use `prevState` in the moveDown function to update the state. Please read about the `updater` function from [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    const { top, rear, transition } = prevState;
    return {
      top: top.filter(x => x !== item),
      rear: [...rear, item],
      transition: {
        ...transition,
        item,
        startTop: itemTop / 5,
        startAnim: false
      }
    };
  });
```

Similarly in you `resetState` function, the state it being mutated. Change it to :

```
  resetState = () => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        transition: { ...transition, startAnim: true }
      }),
      () => {
        console.log("setState finished");
      }
    );
  };
```